# How to rename all files in subdirectories using SSH

Tags: html, ssh, rename

I am trying to rename all html files to "index.html" in my directories, and I can find the .html files using the "find" command, but I can't rename the files using the "rename" command at the same time.

This is my directory structure for example:

```
Test -> Example1 -> Example1.html
Test -> Example2 -> Example2.html
Test -> Example3.html
```

And this is the expected result after renaming the html files:

```
Test -> Example1 -> index.html
Test -> Example2 -> index.html
Test -> index.html
```

After I run the following command it seems that the syntax is correct (no errors), but nothing happened:

```
find . -type f -name "*.html" | rename *.html index.html *html
```

Comment: Where is the relation to `ssh` or `html`?

Comment: In these case I usually use `find` to create some shell commands that (once they look right) can be run by adding a ` | sh` at the end. For example: `find . -name '*.html' | xargs -n 1 | awk '{ print "mv " $1 " " $1 }' | perl -p -e 's,^(.*)[^/]+\.html$,$1/index.html,'`

Answer (score 0):

Your `find` command is right.

```
find . -type f -name \*.html
```

You can run the command and save the output or just use it with pipe `|`

Then you can use `rename` command or **perl** directly or a simple `shell` script.
Usually I use **Perl** itself.

First you need this pattern to match all file names [`(?<=\/)[^\/]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/PIPr9K/1)
Than you can run **perl** like so:

```
# file for test
# list of file which should be renamed (saved by find)
$ cat > file
/one.one/one.one/one.file.html
/two.two/two.two/one.file.html
/three.three/three.three/one.file.html

# dry run
$ perl -lne '($old=$_) && s/(?<=\/)[^\/]+$/index.html/g && print' < file 
/one.one/one.one/index.html
/two.two/two.two/index.html
/three.three/three.three/index.html

# actual rename
# perl -lne '($old=$_) && s/(?<=\/)[^\/]+$/index.html/g && rename($old,$_)'
```

Which means replace any `(?<=\/)[^\/]+$` with `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

When one pipes `find` output or uses `-exec`, there is a race condition where a malicious actor can substitute the files being acted on - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/273965/333919

If you are using GNU find, it provides `-execdir`, allowing:

```
find -type f -name '*.html' -execdir mv -iv \{} index.html \;
```